# How to know the current schema level? Outline Levels?

Tags: excel, vba

Excel allows you to establish the level of the displayed outline, using `Outline.ShowLevels`.

Is there any way to know the levels shown in the current scheme?
Something like  `levels = Outline.Levels`

I'm currently using an auxiliary range on the sheet, where I save the updated outline level:  `.Range("OutlineLevel")`

However, this solution has a couple of major drawbacks:

- The number of levels of the Outline that are initially displayed may be different from that collected in the range.
- The level collected in the range may be higher than the maximum level established in the Outline, because we have no way of knowing this value with any specific property like  `levels = Outline.Levels`.

There does not seem to be any information available on this.

Comment: You can check per row the `OutlineLevel` and you can check `ShowDetail` ... if you tell us, what your exact requirement is, it would be easier to answer.

Comment: Possibly [Determine the number of outline levels using VBA](https://www.office-forums.com/threads/determine-the-number-of-outline-levels-using-vba.1969270/) ?

Comment: Forgive me, MT, but counting hidden rows has no bearing on the existence of a grouping scheme. Rows may be hidden for any other reason. On the other hand, I have never understood why comments are allowed to be used to provide answers.
Anyway, I appreciate your help. All the best.

Comment: Ike, I'm making a small text editor in a spreadsheet, where each line of text takes up one row. Some lines of text are titles and subtitles. I need to group the text by titles and various levels of subtitles. The documentation in the official help is very confusing. I have had to carry out some tests to fully understand how the grouping outlines work. I include an explanation of all this in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given the confusing information on the official help pages, I have conducted my own tests, after which I have come to the following conclusions:

```
'OUTLINE OF GROUPINGS OF A RANK:
'===============================

'In the Excel ribbon:
'Data/Scheme/Group-Ungroup-Subtotal

'In VBA:
'ActiveSheet.Outline

'Show/Hide outline bar:
'----------------------
'ActiveWindow.DisplayOutline = True 'False

'OUTLINE SUMMARY ROWS:
'--------------------------
'It is the visible row of the group, where the +/- _ icon appears
  and it can be at the top or bottom.

'ActiveSheet.Outline.SummaryRow
'Returns or sets the location of the sheet outline summary rows:

'ActiveSheet.Outline.SummaryRow = xlAbove 'xlSummaryAbove 'icons and row summary above
'ActiveSheet.Outline.SummaryRow = xlBelow 'xlSummaryBelow 'icons and summary row below


'Expand or Collapse Groupings of the entire sheet:
'-------------------------------------------------
'ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels([RowLevels], [ColumnLevels])


'Collapse Groupings of the entire sheet:
'--------------------------------------
'ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 1


'Group a range: _
  The specified range must be a row or a column, _
  or a range of rows or columns.
'---------------------------------------------------
'Range.Group
'Range.EntireRow.Group
'Range(Rows(r1), Rows(r2)).Group


'Reduce the grouping level of a range by one level. _
  The specified range must be a row or a column, _
  or a range of rows or columns.
'------------------------------------------------- --------
'Range.Ungroup
'Range.OutlineLevel = Range.OutlineLevel - 1


'Completely ungroup a range:
'---------------------------
'Range.ClearOutline 'Clears the outline of the specified range.
'Range.OutlineLevel = 1
'Rows.Hidden = False 'You need to show hidden rows after ungrouping!


'OUTLINE LEVEL OF A RANGE:
'-------------------------
'Returns or sets the schema level of a range:
'Moves a range (grouped or not) through the different levels of the outline.
'Read and write Variant.

'Range.OutlineLevel = level
'Range.EntireRow.OutlineLevel = level
'Rows(r).OutlineLevel = level
'Range(Rows(r1), Rows(r2)).OutlineLevel = level

'IMPORTANT: It seems that the maximum number of possible levels in a outline is 8

'Level 1:
'--------
'It is the default outline level of a range when it has no groupings.
'If we set the range outline level to 1, grouping is removed from the range.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Range.OutlineLevel = 1 'Remove range grouping!

'Increase or Decrease a grouping level:
'----------------------------------------------
'The following two forms produce the same effect, _
  increase or decrease a grouping level:
'With Range.EntireRow
'    .Ungroup
'    .OutlineLevel = .OutlineLevel - 1
'    .Group
'    .OutlineLevel = .OutlineLevel + 1
'End With


'EXPAND AND COLLAPSE GROUPS (ShowDetail: show/hide detail of the grouped range)
'IMPORTANT: The use of this property is not very clear!!!!
'---------------------------------------------- ---------------------
'NOTE: only works if the range grouping level is within _
       the visible levels set for the sheet by _
       ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels level
'------------------------------------------------- ------------------
'EXPAND GROUP: Show hidden rows within the group:
'Range.ShowDetail = True

'COLLAX GROUP: Hides the rows of the group except the first:
'Range.ShowDetail = False

'CHECK: Know if a group is contracted or expanded:
'expanded = Range.ShowDetail

'IMPORTANT: It can be applied to any row in the group.
'------------------------------------------------- ------------------


'THE FOLLOWING DOES NOT WORK:
'-------------------------
'Locking and unlocking the outline bar when the sheet is protected:
'------------------------------------------------------------------
'ActiveSheet.EnableOutlining 'Reading and writing
'ActiveSheet.EnableOutlining = True 'Not working!!!!!


'Conditional formatting based on outline level:
'------------------------------------------------- ---
'Requires the use of a VBA helper function that _
  we will use with the definition of the conditional format:
'=OutlineLevelFunc(CELL("row",A1)) = i

Function RowOutlineLevel(ByVal r As Long) As Integer
On Error Resume Next

RowOutlineLevel= Rows(r).OutlineLevel

End Function 'RowOutlineLevel
```

The order in which the groupings of the different ranges are made is important, as well as controlling the overlap of groups of different levels.

Since it is somewhat complex to explain, I add a practical example with the procedures to establish and manage groupings with 3 schema levels.

It requires as parameters a column range where the level of each row is marked with a string ("l1", "l2", "l3"), as well as a second column range that serves as a data reference (in this case text), in addition to the three parameters that define the mark corresponding to each level.

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit

'Maximum outline level allowed in Excel:
Public Const C_MaxOutlineLevel = 8

Public Const C_L1 = "l1", _
             C_L2 = "l2", _
             C_L3 = "l3"

Public Const C_InitRowAuxMark = "."


'Maximum level of sheet outline:
'Range(CR_MaxOutlineLevel) = MaxOutlineLevelOfRange(Intersect(sheet.UsedRange, Columns(1)))

Function MaxOutlineLevelOfRange(ByVal columnRng As Range)
'Use: _
maxLevel = MaxOutlineLevelOfRange(columnRng)
Dim maxLevel As Integer
Dim cell As Range

On Error Resume Next

With columnRng.Worksheet

For Each cell In columnRng
    If cell.EntireRow.OutlineLevel > maxLevel Then
       maxLevel = cell.EntireRow.OutlineLevel
       If maxLevel = C_MaxExcelOutlineLevel Then Exit For
    End If
Next

End With

MaxOutlineLevelOfRange = maxLevel

End Function 'MaxOutlineLevelOfRange



'Cell is the beginning of the group?
Function StartOfGroup(cell As Range, _
         Optional levelMark As String) As Boolean
'Use: _
IF StartOfGroup(cell[,levelMark]) Then ...
On Error Resume Next

levelMark = MarcaTexto(cell)

If levelMark = nStr Then Exit Function

StartOfGroup = VBA.InStr(C_L1 & " " & C_L2 & " " & C_L3, levelMark) > 0

End Function 'StartOfGroup




Sub ContractOutlineLevelButton()
On Error Resume Next

AutoOff

ContractExpandSheetOutlineLevel -1
    
AutoOn

End Sub 'ContractOutlineLevelButton



Sub ExpandOutlineLevelButton()
On Error Resume Next

AutoOff

ContractExpandSheetOutlineLevel 1

AutoOn

End Sub 'ExpandOutlineLevelButton



Sub ContractExpandSheetOutlineLevel(ByVal inc As Integer, _
                                 Optional sheet As Worksheet)
'Use: _
ContractExpandSheetOutlineLevel 1/-1 ', sheet
Dim locally As Boolean
Dim level As Integer
Dim maxLevel As Integer
Dim r As Long

On Error Resume Next

'Hide outline bar:
'ActiveWindow.DisplayOutline = False

If sheet Is Nothing Then Set sheet = ActiveSheet

With sheet

dph locally, sheet 'Unprotect/Protect sheet if necessary

'Initial construction of the grouping outline:
If .Range(CR_OutlineLevel) = 0 Then
    BuildSheetOutlineLevels Range(CR_Ref), Range(CR_OutlineLevel), C_L1, C_L2, C_L3
End If

maxLevel = .Range(CR_MaxOutlineLevel)
level = .Range(CR_OutlineLevel) + inc

If level < 1 Or level > maxLevel Then Exit Sub

.Outline.ShowLevels level

.Range(CR_OutlineLevel) = level

'When collapsing, clear auxiliary marks:
If inc = -1 Then
  .Range(CR_AuxLevelMark).ClearContents
  'Select the first visible cell above:
   For r = ActiveCell.Row To .Range(CR_LímiteEdición).Row Step -1
       If Not ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden Then Exit For
       ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Select
   Next
End If

dph locally, sheet 'Unprotect/Protect sheet if necessary

End With

End Sub 'ContractExpandSheetOutlineLevel




Sub ContractExpandGroup(ByVal cell As Range)
'Use: _
ContractExpandGroup cell
Dim eventoLocal As Boolean
Dim locally As Boolean
Dim onOff As Boolean
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim nextCell As Range
Dim levelMark As Range
Dim auxLevelMark As Range
Dim nextMark As String
Dim sheetLevel As Integer
Dim cellLevel As Integer
Dim prevLevel As Integer
Dim nextLevel As Integer
Dim maxLevel As Integer
Dim expandido As Boolean
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Integer

On Error Resume Next

Set sheet = cell.Worksheet

With sheet

Set levelMark = .Cells(cell.Row, .Range(CR_OutlineLevel).Column)

If levelMark = C_InitRowAuxMark Then
   Events localEvent 'Events off if necessary
   cell.Offset(1).Select
   Events localEvent 'Events off if necessary
   Exit Sub
ElseIf Not EsTítulo(levelMark) Then
       Exit Sub
End If

maxLevel = .Range(CR_MaxOutlineLevel)
sheetLevel = .Range(CR_OutlineLevel)
prevLevel = sheetLevel
cellLevel = cell.EntireRow.OutlineLevel

If cellLevel = maxLevel Then Exit Sub

c = cell.Column

AutoOff
dph locally, sheet 'Unprotect/Protect sheet if necessary

Set auxLevelMark = .Cells(cell.Row, .Range(CR_AuxLevelMark).Column)

Set nextCell = cell.Offset(1)
nextMark = .Cells(nextCell.Row, .Range(CR_OutlineLevel).Column)

'Expand group (show only rows of level cellLevel + 1):
If Not cell.EntireRow.ShowDetail And auxLevelMark = nStr Then

   nextLevel = cellLevel
   
   Do
   
     nextLevel = nextLevel + 1
     If nextLevel > maxLevel Then Exit Do
   
    'Show nextLevel level rows:
     For r = cell.Row + 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
         Set nextCell = .Cells(r, c)
         If nextCell.EntireRow.OutlineLevel <= cellLevel Then Exit For
         If nextCell.EntireRow.OutlineLevel = nextLevel Then
            nextCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            If nextCell.RowHeight > 1 Then _
               expandido = True
         End If
     Next
     
    'Update sheet level:
     If expandido Then
     
        If nextLevel > sheetLevel Then .Range(CR_OutlineLevel) = nextLevel
       
        Exit Do
        
     End If
       
   Loop

'Expand auxiliary group with last level rows:
ElseIf auxLevelMark = nStr And _
       nextMark = C_InitRowAuxMark And _
       cell.Offset(2).EntireRow.Hidden Then
       
      'Show hidden rows:
       For r = cell.Row + 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
           Set nextCell = .Cells(r, c)
           nextLevel = nextCell.EntireRow.OutlineLevel
           If nextLevel <> maxLevel Then Exit For
           nextCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
       Next
       
       auxLevelMark = "*"

      .Range(CR_OutlineLevel) = maxLevel
     
'Group expanded (collapse):
Else
       
   'If there are top-level rows visible then collapse only those rows:
    If auxLevelMark <> nStr And _
       nextMark = C_InitRowAuxMark And _
       Not cell.Offset(2).EntireRow.Hidden Then
       
       For r = cell.Row + 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
           Set nextCell = .Cells(r, c)
           nextLevel = nextCell.EntireRow.OutlineLevel
           If nextLevel <> maxLevel Then Exit For
           nextCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Next
       
       If Not cell.EntireRow.ShowDetail Then auxLevelMark = nStr
       
      .Range(CR_OutlineLevel) = sheetLevel - 1
       
   'Collapse group (show only level -1 rows):
    ElseIf cell.EntireRow.ShowDetail Then
    
           cell.EntireRow.ShowDetail = False
           
           auxLevelMark = nStr
           
           If cellLevel = sheetLevel - 1 Then .Range(CR_OutlineLevel) = cellLevel
   
   'Restore auxiliary mark:
    Else
        auxLevelMark = nStr
    End If

End If

dph locally, sheet 'Unprotect/Protect sheet if necessary
AutoOn

End With

End Sub 'ContractExpandGroup





Sub BuildSheetOutlineLevels(ByVal refRng As Range, _
                            ByVal levelsRng As Range, _
                       ParamArray levels())
'Use: _
BuildSheetOutlineLevels refRng, levelsRng, level1, level2, level3, ...
Dim onOff As Boolean
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim actCell As Range
Dim prevCell As Range
Dim nextCell As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim maxR As Long
Dim level As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim accLevel As Integer
Dim maxLevel As Integer
Dim init As Long
Dim fin As Long
Dim initR() As Long
Dim finR() As Long

On Error Resume Next

AutoOff

Set sheet = refRng.Worksheet

With sheet

''Show outline bar (for testing only):
'ActiveWindow.DisplayOutline = True

Show +/- icons and summary rows (group visible row) _
 at the top of the group:
ActiveSheet.Outline.SummaryRow = xlAbove 'xlSummaryAbove 'Arriva

'Show all rows:
If .FilterMode Then .UsedRange.AutoFilter
Set actCell = ActiveCell
.Rows.ClearOutline
.UsedRange.EntireRow.Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
actCell.Select

ResetUsedRange refRng

maxR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
maxR = maxR + maxR / 5

maxLevel = UBound(levels) - LBound(levels) + 1

ReDim initR(maxLevel)
ReDim finR(maxLevel)

For r = .Range(CR_LímiteEdición).Row + 1 To maxR
    
    Set cell = Cells(r, refRng.Column)
    
'   'For test only.
'    cell.Select
'    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = cell.Row - 6

    level = Cells(r, levelsRng.Column)

   'Level 1:
    If level = levels(1 - 1) Then
          
      'Start of level 1:
       If initR(1) = 0 Then
       
          initR(1) = r + 1
          
      'Fin del level 1:
      'End of level 1:
       Else
            
          'If there is level 3 pending grouping:
           If initR(3) <> 0 Then
              finR(3) = r - 1
              With .Range(.Rows(initR(3)), .Rows(finR(3)))
                   .Group
              End With
           End If
           
          'If there is level 2 pending grouping:
           If initR(2) <> 0 Then
              finR(2) = r - 1
              With .Range(.Rows(initR(2)), .Rows(finR(2)))
                   .Group
              End With
           End If

           finR(1) = r - 1
           With .Range(.Rows(initR(1)), .Rows(finR(1)))
                .Group
                 If initR(2) = 0 Then .Group
                 If initR(3) = 0 Then .Group
           End With
           initR(1) = r + 1
       End If
       
      'If the following row is a group auxiliary row, delete it:
       Set nextCell = cell.Offset(1)
       If nextCell.RowHeight = 0 Then nextCell.EntireRow.Delete
       
      'By grouping levels, we reset counters for lower levels:
       initR(2) = 0
       initR(3) = 0
          
       accLevel = 1 'Nivel acumulado. 'Accumulated level.
       
   'Level 2:
    ElseIf level = levels(2 - 1) Then
       
          'Start of level 2:
           If initR(2) = 0 Then
           
             'First level 2 group within level 1, group initial rows before the new group:
              If accLevel = 1 And r > initR(1) + 1 Then 'initR(1) > 0
                 
                'IMPORTANT: It is necessary to add a semi-hidden auxiliary row _
                            at the beginning of the previous group to separate levels:
                 Set prevCell = .Cells(initR(1), cell.Column)
                 If prevCell <> nStr Then
                    prevCell.EntireRow.Insert
                    prevCell.Offset(-1).RowHeight = 0.1 '0.4 Minimum height so that the row is not hidden.
                   'Mark the auxiliary row for later recognition:
                   .Cells(prevCell.Row - 1, .Range(CR_Marca).Column) = C_InitRowAuxMark
                    r = r + 1
                 End If
          
                 initR(2) = initR(1) + 1
                 finR(2) = r - 1
                'Group and sink group to maximum level:
                 With .Range(.Rows(initR(2)), .Rows(finR(2)))
                      .Group
                      .Group
                 End With
              End If
           
              initR(2) = r + 1
              
          'Fin del level 2:
          'End of level 2:
           Else
                 
              'If there is level 3 pending grouping:
               If initR(3) <> 0 Then
                  finR(3) = r - 1
                 .Range(.Rows(initR(3)), .Rows(finR(3))).Group
               End If
           
               finR(2) = r - 1
               With .Range(.Rows(initR(2)), .Rows(finR(2)))
                    .Group
                     If initR(3) = 0 Then .Group
               End With
               initR(2) = r + 1
           End If
       
          'If the following row is blank, delete it:
           Set nextCell = cell.Offset(1)
           If nextCell.RowHeight = 0 Then nextCell.EntireRow.Delete
       
          'By grouping levels, we reset counters for lower levels:
           initR(3) = 0
           
           accLevel = 2 'Nivel acumulado. 'Accumulated level.
       
   'Level 3:
    ElseIf level = levels(3 - 1) Then
           
          'Start of level 3:
           If initR(3) = 0 Then
       
             'First level 3 group within level 2 or level 1, group initial rows before the new group:
              If initR(1) > 0 And initR(2) = 0 And r > initR(1) + 1 Or _
                 initR(2) > 0 And r > initR(2) + 1 Then
                 
                 If initR(2) > 0 Then
                    init = initR(2)
                 ElseIf initR(1) > 0 Then
                        init = initR(1)
                 End If
                 
                'IMPORTANT: It is necessary to add a semi-hidden auxiliary row _
                            at the beginning of the previous group to separate levels:
                 Set prevCell = .Cells(init, cell.Column)
                 If prevCell <> nStr Then
                    prevCell.EntireRow.Insert
                    prevCell.Offset(-1).RowHeight = 0.1 '0.4 Minimum height so that the row is not hidden.
                   'Mark the auxiliary row for later recognition:
                   .Cells(prevCell.Row - 1, .Range(CR_Marca).Column) = C_InitRowAuxMark
                    r = r + 1
                 End If
              
                 init = init + 1
                 fin = r - 1
                'Group and sink group to maximum level:
                 With .Range(.Rows(init), .Rows(fin))
                      .Group
                 End With
              End If
           
              initR(3) = r + 1
           
              accLevel = 3 'Nivel acumulado. 'Accumulated level.
              
          'End of level 3 (group):
           Else
               finR(3) = r - 1
               With .Range(.Rows(initR(3)), .Rows(finR(3)))
                    .Group
               End With
               initR(3) = r + 1
           End If
       
         'If the following row is blank, delete it:
          Set nextCell = cell.Offset(1)
          If nextCell.RowHeight = 0 Then nextCell.EntireRow.Delete
       
          'By grouping the level, we reset counters for the lower levels:
          'What is the last level like, there is none.
       
   'Last row of .UsedRange:
    ElseIf r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
           
          'If there is level 3 pending grouping:
           If initR(3) <> 0 Then
              finR(3) = r
             .Range(.Rows(initR(3)), .Rows(finR(3))).Group
           End If
           
          'If there is level 2 pending grouping:
           If initR(2) <> 0 Then
              finR(2) = r
              With .Range(.Rows(initR(2)), .Rows(finR(2)))
                   .Group
                    If initR(3) = 0 Then .EntireRow.OutlineLevel = .EntireRow.OutlineLevel + 1
              End With
           End If
           
          'If there is level 1 pending grouping:
           If initR(1) <> 0 Then
              finR(1) = r
              With .Range(.Rows(initR(1)), .Rows(finR(1)))
                   .Group
              End With
           End If
           
           Exit For

    End If
    
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

.Range(CR_MaxOutlineLevel) = MaxOutlineLevelOfRange(Intersect(sheet.UsedRange, Columns(1)))
.Range(CR_OutlineLevel) = .Range(CR_MaxOutlineLevel)

End With

AutoOn

End Sub 'BuildSheetOutlineLevels







'Outline levels testing:
Sub OutlineLevelTest()
On Error Resume Next

'dph 'Unprotect activesheet if necessary.
'
'Range(CR_MaxOutlineLevel) = MaxOutlineLevelOfRange(Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns(1)))

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'
'Show or hide outline bar:
'ActiveWindow.DisplayOutline = True
'ActiveWindow.DisplayOutline = False

'ActiveSheet.Outline.SummaryRow = xlAbove 'xlSummaryAbove 'Arriva
'ActiveSheet.Outline.SummaryRow = xlBelow 'xlSummaryBelow 'Abajo

BuildSheetOutlineLevels Range(CR_Ref), Range(CR_OutlineLevel), C_L1, C_L2, C_L3

'The following two forms produce the same effect, increase or decrease a grouping level:
'With Selection.EntireRow
'    .Ungroup
'    .OutlineLevel = .OutlineLevel - 1
'    .Group
'    .OutlineLevel = .OutlineLevel + 1
'End With

'IMPORTANT: We check that .ShowLevels 1 + .ShowDetail = True _
 shows the grouping detail up to the level set to _
 previous ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels:
'----------------------------------------

'ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 2 'Shows all groups on the sheet up to level 2
'ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 1 'Hide all groups
'ActiveCell.EntireRow.ShowDetail = True 'Shows the details of the selected group up to level 2
'
'ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 3 'Shows all groups on the sheet up to level 3
'ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 1 'Hide all groups
'ActiveCell.EntireRow.ShowDetail = True 'Shows the details of the selected group up to level 3

'ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 4 'Shows all groups on the sheet up to level 4
'ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 1 'Hide all groups
'ActiveCell.EntireRow.ShowDetail = True 'Shows the details of the selected group up to level 4

'ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 3
'ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 1
'ActiveCell.EntireRow.ShowDetail = True
'
'ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 2
'ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 1
'ActiveCell.EntireRow.ShowDetail = True

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub 'OutlineLevelTest
```

[image]